# When I use any git command I get a "fatal: bad config file line"

Tags: git, github

I keep getting a:

"fatal bad config file line 19 in/Users/fernandofernandez/.gitconfig"

every time I  use a git command.  I discovered this when I tried to "git init" a new folder.  After researching and trying different things I decided to check a folder I had just recently used git successfully and got the same error (bad config file line 19 in/Users/fernandofernandez/.gitconfig).  I "cat ~/.gitconfig" to see the file:

```
[core]
    editor = vim -w
    excludesfile = /Users/fernandofernandez/.gitignore_global
[user]
    name = Fernando
    email = ffmp777@yahoo.com
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh\"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[push]
    default = simple
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
??5??`?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku??`?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku
```

I feel comfortable using git on the command line, but not enough to see the error or what I need to do to fix it.  If anyone knows what may be going on, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: that happen when you are as administrator, just before use the command sudo and i think all is will fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message `bad config file line 19 in/Users/fernandofernandez/.gitconfig` would suggest an error on line 19. Line 19 in your config file is the following:

```
??5??`?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku??`?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku
```

Delete this line, everything else seems to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to fix the changes you made in this file like this

```
??5??`?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku??`?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?ku?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?kd?ku?ku
```

if you don't know how to open this file again, go to the directory you are in via terminal and

> cd .git

mac users can see the file as

> ls -A

After entering the .git file, we can open our config file with the vim editor as follows

> vim config

You can correct the files that we corrupted with our own hands, press the esc key then save and exit as follows.

> :x